# Extensions in tar.gz format

Tags: development, extensions

Can you tell me whether `tar.gz` format is commonly used for Joomla extension packs? Because Google marks all `zip` archives that are not commonly downloaded as malicious, I am thinking to change the format of my extensions from `zip` to `tar.gz`. Who knows if there are any downsides in `tar.gz` format?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to this [book](https://books.google.com/books?id=o68lyZWZDJQC&pg=PT114&lpg=PT114&dq=joomla%20tar.gz%20support) .zip format is most commonly used format for joomla extension but Joomla supports both .zip and .tar.gz. However some web hosts don't support .tar.gz

Comment: Some web hosts do not support .tar.gz -- this is what I am afraid of. Could you, please, provide more information on this issue, what kind of hosts possibly cannot support this format?

Comment: To be honest, I'm not really sure about that. Maybe you can try to ask it at http://serverfault.com/

Comment: @webchun http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14071/joomla only just saw your comment :/